# Conditionally retry a job when exception occurred

Tags: laravel

I'm dealing with an exteranl api which has rate limit system on some of their endpoint,So i want to delay and retry a job when the api return a rate limit error like so:

```php
abstract class Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;


    public function failed(Throwable $e)
    {
        // get subclass error and release the current job later if it rate limited
        if ($later = Str::match('~retry after (\d+)~', $e->getMessage())) {
            $this->release($later); // its not working becuase the $this->job is null here (dont know why)
        }
    }
}
```

```php
class SendDailyMessage extends Job
{
    public function __construct(public int $userId)
    {

    }

    public function handle()
    {
        Telegram::sendMessage($this->userId, 'message'); // it throws exception on rate limit
    }
}
```

```
php artisan queue:work --tries=2 --sleep=3
```

I have multiple jobs like the above class so i put the logic in the parent class for all of them, the problem is the `$this->release` not working and the job never get back to the queue (driver: database)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to run $this->release(...) manually. If there's an exception, job will be released automatically (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#error-handling).
Also you can try setting properties $tries and $maxTries in your job class.

Comment: I want to delay the job base on the "rate limit" from the api (look the first snippet), the job itself doesnt know for how long it should wait to retry it again (it's dynamic on every request), Besides, the `$tries` and `$maxTries` is not related to this issue

Comment: Then you should consider $backoff property: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs

Comment: Let me more clear, `Telegram::sendMessage()` throws an exception and says "retry after 20 second" so i have to book the job for 20 second later, its not always 20second its different on requests, on the other hand all of the properties took place when we dispatch job before the exception accurs right? so if we got "retry after 1200 second" it's different than prev error

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly at which time "backoff" property is taken into account (before "failed" method or after). But you can try to experiment with it. Btw, you can use "release" method inside "handle" method. Use try/catch statement to catch your error inside "handle" method.